# C++: shared_ptr not playing nicely with templated function

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm having some trouble getting shared pointers to work with a templated data-managing function. I have some simple structs that contain loaded data for various objects, as such:

```
struct loadedShipData_t {
    enum VARIABLES {
        // snip for readability: lots of variable names for identification
    };

    std::string textureKey;
    std::array<int, 20> data;
};

struct loadedStarfieldData_t {
    enum VARIABLES {
        // snip for readability: lots of variable names for identification
    };

    std::array<int, 8> data;
};
```

When an instance of these data structs is constructed, a pointer there-to is inserted its respective unordered map (one per data type), so that they can be accessed whenever needed, e.g.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<loadedShipData_t>> shipData;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<loadedStarfieldData_t>> starfieldData;
```

...and so forth.

The templated function that I am having trouble implementing is one called getData, which returns a pointer to a data struct stored in its unordered map given a key.

```
template <typename DATA>
    std::shared_ptr<DATA> getData(DATA_TYPES dataType, const std::string& key) {
        switch (dataType) {
            case STARFIELD_DATA:
                return starfieldData.at(key);
            case SHIP_DATA:
                return shipData.at(key);
            // snip for readability: all the other data types
            default:
                throw UNDEFINED_DATA_TYPE();
                break;
        };
    }
```

This function is called as such:

```
std::shared_ptr<loadedStarfieldData_t> loadedData = data.getData<loadedStarfieldData_t>(STARFIELD_DATA, key);
std::shared_ptr<loadedShipData_t> loadedShipData = data.getData<loadedShipData_t>(SHIP_DATA, "Debug");
```

And the error message:

```
<file_path> error C2664: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
          with
          [
              _Ty=loadedShipData_t
          ]
          and
          [
              _Ty=loadedStarfieldData_t
          ]
          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
          <file_path> : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> DataManager::getData<loadedShipData_t>(DATA_TYPES,const std::string &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=loadedShipData_t
          ]
<file_path> error C2664: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
          with
          [
              _Ty=loadedStarfieldData_t
          ]
          and
          [
              _Ty=loadedShipData_t
          ]
          // snip for readability: other data types
          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
          <file_path> : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> DataManager::getData<loadedStarfieldData_t>(DATA_TYPES,const std::string &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty=loadedStarfieldData_t
          ]
          // snip for readability: other data types
```

I've looked over and messed with the code countless times to no end, so I thought I'd see if anybody else had encountered similar issues. I found a couple of similar questions here but wasn't able to figure out what was going wrong, so I figured I'd post the details of my own problem and see if any of the C++ gurus in these parts could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your time and consideration!

P.S. I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2012, if that helps.

Comment: Why not have separate `getStarFieldData` and `getShipData` functions?

Comment: I suppose I just wanted to be lazy, since there are a lot of data types. Ah, well! Thanks for the suggestion, I'll probably just end up doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert a `shared_ptr<loadedShipData_t>` to a `shared_ptr<loadedStarfieldData_t>` by the looks of it. As a guess, they are probably incompatible pointer types, and this doesn't work for the same reason that trying to return a `loadedShipData_t*` from a function declared to return a `loadedStarfieldData_t*` wouldn't work.

To expand on this, the line:

```
std::shared_ptr<loadedStarfieldData_t> loadedData = data.getData<loadedStarfieldData_t> STARFIELD_DATA, key);
```

turns your template basically into this:

```
std::shared_ptr<loadedStarfieldData_t> getData(DATA_TYPES dataType, const std::string& key) {
    switch (dataType) {
        case STARFIELD_DATA:
            return starfieldData.at(key);
        case SHIP_DATA:
            return shipData.at(key); // <-- type mismatch here
        // snip for readability: all the other data types
        default:
            throw UNDEFINED_DATA_TYPE();
            break;
    };
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, since the starfield call is entirely unattached to the ship call. Or are you referring to something specific in the code I posted that I'm not seeing? I added an example call for the loadedShipData_t struct as well as the loadedStarfieldData_t struct to the original post for increased clarity.

Comment: Exactly so. *You* may know that only one of the return statements will be executed, but the compiler will compile the others anyway.

Comment: You can't return two different types from the same function, even if that function is a template. You have to have some kind of common type that they can both convert to in order to do that.

Comment: @Samuel: The function does not know that for a given T, that the only case in the switch that will be hit is the corresponding one. All possible returns in the function must return a type convertible to the function's return type. Templates are "fancy pants find and replace" -- if it wouldn't work replacing T with some specific type then it won't work for templates either. (You might be able to get around it in this particular case using tag dispatch/partial specialization)

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose that makes sense. How would you recommend I go about fixing this, then, since I would still very much like to have a single function for fetching the various data types -- or is that simply not feasible?

Comment: I think I'll simply stop trying to be clever and stick with a bunch of dedicated getter functions for my data types. Thanks a bunch for your help and advice, guys!

Answer (score 2):

A function template is not a function that can magically change its type at runtime. It is not a function at all. It is a recipe to make regular, non-magic functions. If you cannot write a function that does what you want with a fixed set of types, you cannot write a magic template that does it either.

You are trying to write a function that would return either type A or type B, depending on a run-time argument. Such functions do not exist in C++ and you cannot make them using a template.

Comment: Yeah, it makes a lot of sense that what I was trying to do wasn't going to work -- I'm not quite sure why I was convinced that it was feasible in the first place! Thanks for the help.